# rclone and set/reset public access level of azure container

Tags: command-line, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, fedora, rclone

It seems that the tool `rclone` has limitation not to allow set/reset public access level to either blob or container of a container either at the time of creation or later. Container has default public access level set to `private`.

Here is the rclone command to create a container if does not exists

> rclone mkdir azure:mycontainer

There is `azure-ctl` command that seems working fine and able to set/reset this level. However same is missing from the `rclone` tool. Or possibly I'm not able to figure out how to do it using `rclone`.

> az storage container create 
> --name  
> --account-name  
> --resource-group 
> --public-access off 
> --account-key  
> --auth-mode key

Details:

```
Rclone v1.48.0
Fedora 29, 64 bit
```

Comment: Would you mind accept my reply as answer? Or you can post another reply to let others know and close this issue.

Comment: I'm waiting for the code to be merged to the `rclone` main repo so that next release should work like azure-ctl tool and then I will add my answer. I've upvoted your answer anyway.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks for your contribution.@MaNKuR

Answer (score 1):

After checking with the [docs](https://rclone.org/azureblob/), we found that we cannot set/reset the public access level using Rclone tools.

You can do that with [the ways below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#set-the-public-access-level-for-a-container):

1. Set on Portal:
   [image]
2. Use powershell command:

   ```
    # Set variables.
    $rgName = "<resource-group>"
    $accountName = "<storage-account>"

    # Get context object.
    $storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $accountName
    $ctx = $storageAccount.Context

    # Create a new container with public access setting set to Off.
    $containerName = "<container>"
    New-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Permission Off -Context $ctx

    # Read the container's public access setting.
    Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Container $containerName -Context $ctx

    # Update the container's public access setting to Container.
    Set-AzStorageContainerAcl -Container $containerName -Permission Container -Context $ctx

    # Read the container's public access setting.
    Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Container $containerName -Context $ctx
   ```
3. Use Azure CLI command:

   ```
    az storage container create \
        --name <container-name> \
        --account-name <account-name> \
        --resource-group <resource-group>
        --public-access off \
        --account-key <account-key> \
        --auth-mode key

    az storage container show-permission \
        --name <container-name> \
        --account-name <account-name> \
        --account-key <account-key> \
        --auth-mode key

    az storage container set-permission \
        --name <container-name> \
        --account-name <account-name> \
        --public-access container \
        --account-key <account-key> \
        --auth-mode key

    az storage container show-permission \
        --name <container-name> \
        --account-name <account-name> \
        --account-key <account-key> \
        --auth-mode key
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detail info. Yes I'm aware of those options but wanted this to be added to the `rclone` tool. I had look through the `rclone` pkg and found its missing and the next version would have it.